# Use both Jade and html in the same Node and express Project

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm working on Email Html template. I want to use jade and html in the same node project. Is there any package available where I can convert my jade file into html?

Comment: doesn't pug (jade) have a javascript function to convert .pug files to html?

Comment: Why do you need to convert jade into HTML?  This would reduce your render performance as it moves processing from in-memory to reading from disk.